# Django Model form not saving data to the database model on form submission

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have created a project and added models in the models and also created a form in forms.py. I am trying to modify some values using the `commit=False`. On submitting the form, it's not saving the data to the database and there is no error thrown from the code. I have no idea on how  I can solve the issue.

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Agent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    id_no = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=8)
    age    = models.IntegerField()
    agent_no = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=12, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name}"


class Company(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    telephone = models.IntegerField( null=True, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name}"


class Task(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    agent = models.ForeignKey(Agent, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    cargo = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    document = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/')
    quantity = models.FloatField()
    amount = models.FloatField()
    duty = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='Pending')
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.cargo}"
```

forms.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django import forms
import re
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from .models import *

class TaskForm(forms.ModelForm):
    cargo = forms.CharField( required=False)
    document = forms.FileField()
    quantity = forms.FloatField()
    amount = forms.FloatField()

    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = ['cargo', 'document', 'quantity', 'amount']
```

views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import *
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate


@login_required(login_url='/login/')
def task(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form=TaskForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            m = form.save(commit=False)
            m.status ='Pending'
            m.company = request.user.username
            m.save()
 

    else:
        form= TaskForm(None)
    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'registration/templates/task.html', context)
```

template.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}

<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="container my-2 d-flex" style="align-items:center; justify-content:center;">
        <div class="card d-flex" style="width:70%; align-items:center; justify-content:center;">
            <div class="form-control pt-3 " style="text-transform:uppercase;color:green"><h5>Upload trip information
                </h5>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body" style="width:98%">
                {{ form|crispy}}
            </div>
              <div class="card-footer" style="width:98%">
                  <input type="submit" value="Upload Information" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: You don't need to re-define the fields in your form. remove the fields there and just use `fields = [...]` and your form will map them to your model fields. You define fields when you want extra data or some other type of fields and then you have to add them manually using `save()` method.

Comment: I have tried this but still it's not working

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.urls import reverse
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from .forms import *
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate


@login_required(login_url='/login/')
def task(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form=TaskForm(request.POST,request.FILES) # this is important if you are dealing with files
        if form.is_valid():
            m = form.save(commit=False)
            m.status ='Pending'
            m.company = request.user.username
            m.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(' the url of where you want to redirect the user '))

    else:
        form= TaskForm()
    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'registration/templates/task.html', context)
```

and in your templates try to add enctype in your form.

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="container my-2 d-flex" style="align-items:center; justify-content:center;">
        <div class="card d-flex" style="width:70%; align-items:center; justify-content:center;">
            <div class="form-control pt-3 " style="text-transform:uppercase;color:green"><h5>Upload trip information
                </h5>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body" style="width:98%">
                {{ form|crispy }}
            </div>
              <div class="card-footer" style="width:98%">
                  <input type="submit" value="Upload Information" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```